# How do I export a JavaFX with extra modules to a JAR

Tags: java, javafx, java-platform-module-system

I currently have an application utilizing some imported modules like Jackson and MSSQL JDBC. I don't currently use any tool like Maven, Gradle or ANT.
I've tried to export the JavaFX JAR with them extracted in the JAR like shown in the picture below.
[image: Screenshot of artifact with extracted modules]

But then I get the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class apicall.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apicall.Main
```

When I include them without extracting them like in the picture below:

[image: Screenshot of artifact without extracted modules]

Then the application runs but throws out the following error when I try to do a call to the SQL database: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver`

I currently run the JAR by typing the following command in the console:

```
java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar APICall.jar
```

How do I export the JavaFX JAR with all my required modules to run with the same or similar command as I listed above?

Edit: The JAR structure is as follows:
[image: JAR Structure]

And the Stack trace looks like this:
[image: Stack trace SQL error]

Comment: Your JAR structure is wrong. In the second case it all comes down to the class loader and where it's actually trying to find the JDBC driver. These are exactly the type of problems plugins like the maven shader plugin solve. We would need to see more of the file structure to be able to answer this correctly.

Comment: I am fully new to JavaFX, what else can I show to help get to an answer?

Comment: This is not a JavaFX issue - it's related to the classloader having trouble finding your classes. We need to see the full file structure of the JAR. Viewing the MANIFEST file would also be helpful.

Comment: @X.Tamis can you provide your maven packaging configuration? (build info from pom.xml)

Comment: @NagarajTantri As stated in the original question - OP is not using Maven. So there's simply not enough to go on without a more complete view of the structure of the JAR file.

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg, yes saw it again, my bad. But yes, there is very little information on then the compile view.

Comment: You could use jlink to create JRE with compatible JavaFX built in.

Comment: I think a part of the problem with this is using "-jar". That changes the class path, and I doubt it would work a module. Have you tried reducing this problem down to just a javafx app?

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg Where do I find the complete view of the structure of the JAR file?

Comment: @X.Tamis You would have to take a look at the JAR file and list the contents. It's essentially a zip file - so you can list it the same way you would any zip.

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg I have added a screenshot with the contents of the JAR file, I hope this is sufficient otherwise I will update it asap! Thanks for the help so far

Comment: @X.Tamis The JAR with the above structure throws which error ? I'm asuming it's the SQLException one ? What's in your MANIFEST file ?

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg The SQLException is what I get, indeed. The MANIFEST file only has 2 lines in it: 
"Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: apicall.MainApplication"

Comment: What is the content of your META-INF/services folder?

Comment: @X.Tamis So depending on what's creating that exception you have a couple of options to try. You might be able to just unpack `mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre14.jar` and put it directly into the root of the jar. Second option is to add it to the classpath inside the MANIFEST file. Third option is to add the mysql  dependency as a module and add it into your module path/description so it can access it. Do you have a stack trace of the `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver` exception? I'm asking because I'm wondering exactly what dependency is triggering this.

Comment: @Mumrah81 In my META-INF/services folder, I have a single file called `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec`

Comment: You're missing /META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver to register your driver, see updated answer below

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg I have added a screenshot with the stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends of one thing :

```
is APICall a modular jar? does it contains a module-info.java?
```

- if APICall is a modular jar it can only access packages exported by modules and can't access the classpath.
- if APICall isn't a modular jar then it must become an "automatic-module" to give it access to packages exported by modules and classpath.

From the list of dependencies provided:

- javafx dependencies are modules
- jackson dependencies are modules
- commons-io is not a module
- mysql-jdbc is not a module

So let's talk about the first option

**APICall is a module**

It means, the jar contains a module-info and explicitly requires needed packages for his execution. It also means APICall can't access commons-io and mysql-jdbc if they are in the classpath. So commons-io and mysql-jdbc must be added to the module-path to be converted to automatic-module and becomnig accessible. Appropriate "require" clauses must be added to the module-info file.

For running the application you need to provide 3 things:

- where to find the dependent modules and the main module using --module-path or -p
- which module is the main module using --module or -m
- the main class to run (if not provided by the MANIFEST file)

The command would be something like:

```
java --module-path <list of folders containing javafx/jacksons/commons/mysqljdbc/APICall jars> --module <APICall module name>/apicall.Main
```

**APICall isn't a module**

It means, the jar doesn't contains a module-info and required module dependencies must be provided explicitly in the command line. It also means APICall must become an automatic-module to access modules and classpath.

For running the application you need to provide 4 things:

- where to find the dependent modules using --module-path or -p
- where to find the dependent non modular jars using --class-path or -classpath or -cp
- which module is the main module using --module or -m
- the main class to run (if not provided by the MANIFEST file)

Knowing the automatic-module name if not provided in the MANIFEST file is the jar name striped from the version then APICall.jar automatic module name will be "APICall"

The command would be something like:

```
java --module-path <list of folders containing javafx/jacksons/APICall jars> --add-modules <list of module names required by APICall> --class-path <path to commons-io/mysql-jdbc jars> --module APICall/apicall.Main
```

PS: if you don't want to provide the list of module to load to the --add-modules argument you can use this constant "ALL-MODULE-PATH" which will load all the modules found in the module path

English is not my language so i hope i was clear enought

EDIT:

**About your APICall.jar:**

The internal structure can't be loaded as is. Jar can't contains jar.
It can be achieved by using a custom classloader but it will be a tought nutt to crack. Springboot uses this kind of classloader if you want to take a look.

Anyway, i'm guessing you're trying to create a "fat" jar. To create a fat jar manualy is a bad idea. So much mistakes can be done. So i advise you to use some build tools like gradle or maven to create it.

Those are some remarks about the content of your jar:

- **apicall**: the base package of your app, this is OK
- **com**: another base package, probably the result of extracting javafx or jackson's dependencies. OK
- **javafx**: base package, result of extracting javafx's jar. You're already providing those modules using --module-path so why including them in your jar?
- **javafx.base**: module extracted from javafx.base.jar. KO. A jar can't contains modules, only packages. "javafx.base" is not a valid package name. This won't be loaded
- **javafx.controls**: same as previous
- **javafx.fxml**: same as previous
- **javafx.graphics**: same as previous
- **javafx.media**: same as previous
- **javafx.swing**: same as previous
- **javafx.web**: same as previous
- **META-INF**: contains a MANIFEST file that may contains the main class of your app. The most important point is the "service" folder. It must contains files named the same as the service interface they provide containing the list of implementing classes. *Jackson and mssql jars provide those services. Did you add/merge those files?*
- **microsoft**: If you're creating a fat jar this one is missing. This package exists in mssql-driver jar but not in your jar
- **mssql**: If you're creating a fat jar this one is missing. This package exists in mssql-driver jar but not in your jar
- **org**: If you're creating a fat jar this one is missing. This package exists in commons-io jar but not in your jar
- **commons-io-2.8.0.jar**: not accessible, must be extracted
- **jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar**: not accessible, must be extracted
- **jackson-core-2.11.3.jar**: not accessible, must be extracted
- **jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar**: not accessible, must be extracted
- **module-info.class**: what's inside?
- **mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre14.jar**: not accessible, must be extracted

To conclude : your jar is a mess.

I advise you to:

- do not create a fat jar and use the solutions provided at the top of this post
- use a fat jar but make it using gradle or maven

EDIT:

And to add to the list of things **that ARE wrong**

From your comment your'e missing the file

```
/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver
```

This file is needed to register Drivers for the java.sql API

You can find one in mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre14.jar, which contains the line

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Without it, you will always get a:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. It's just a big list of things that can go wrong. The question needs more work and clarity - at the moment this answer doesn't help.

Comment: The clarity of the answer is linked to the clarity of the question. Anyway, the answer is updated

Comment: @Mumrah81I will try your suggestions later today when I have the time, thank you for the help so far. I have awarded you the bounty for now, because you've put a lot of effort into helping me.

Comment: @Mumrah81 I have a module-info.class file in my JAR but not a module-info.java, does that mean that APICall is a modular JAR? I have removed the other JavaFX folders and the other JARs from the APICall JAR and put them outside in a Library folder, how do I call upon all of them in the module-path?

Comment: So you don't have the sources of APICall? It may be modular but if the module-info comes from the extraction of javafx modules, it may not. Without sources it will be hard to guess. Anyway, let's say you put your jars in C:/Tmp/Library then the command is java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15\lib;C:\Tmp\Library" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --module APICall/apicall.Main. Note that "APICall" is my guess of the module name and may be different than the one provided in module-info.class

Comment: @X.Tamis Another option i did not provide in my answer is the possibility to completely drop the module system and use the legacy way of putting all jars into the classpath. The command would be:  java --classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15\lib\\*;C:\Tmp\Library\\*" apicall.Main

Comment: @Mumrah81 The module-info indeed came from the extraction of the JavaFX modules, so I've tried doing it the legacy way by putting all the JARs into the classpath with your command. I got the exception `Unrecognized option: --classpath Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.` Sorry if the solution might seem obvious to you, I am a total Java beginner

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake use -classpath instead

Comment: @Mumrah81 I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class apicall.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apicall.Main`

Comment: @X.Tamis can you share the executed command? And verify apicall/Main.class exists in the jar?

Comment: @Mumrah81 I run the following command: `java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15\lib\*;C:\Tmp\Library\*" apicall.Main` Inside the JAR, there's an apicall folder with Main.class inside

Comment: @X.Tamis Is APICall.jar inside C:\Tmp\Library\ ? Can you share APICall.jar using some filesharing service?

Comment: @Mumrah81 APICall was not inside C:\Tmp\Library, I have moved it to that folder and got the error that the JavaFX runtime was missing. But with the following command I got it working: `java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -classpath "C:\Tmp\Library\*" apicall.Main`. Could doing it this way cause any problems in the future?

Comment: @X.Tamis Your app is in the classpath and have access to javafx modules. If you're using non exported javafx packages or try to use reflection then you may have to add --add-open or --add-export args to your command but don't worry error messages will be explicit on what you have to do to solve it